# Why SpringDoc OpenAPI doesn't understand MultipartFile payload?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, multipartfile

I'm working on a Spring boot application which has a controller to help upload `Multipart` files:

```
@PostMapping("/files")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFiles(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] file, String comment) 
        throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    log.debug("Total files to store: {}", file.length);
    log.debug("comment: {}", comment);
    fileService.storeFile(Arrays.asList(file), comment);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(environment.getProperty("file.upload.success"));
}
```

**Problem:** Somehow OpenDocAPI (swagger) doesn't understand this payload as file.

It shows this field as `String` if I mention `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file` or `String[]` if I use array of MultipartFiles.

My Spring boot parent:

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.7.1</version>
```

The spring doc openapi dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

The swagger page:

[image]

The result page when I click on <kbd>Try it out</kbd>:

[image]

The <kbd>Execute</kbd> button doesn't work

Any idea what am I missing in the controller?

**PS -** I tried with mentioning:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/files", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
```

But still OpenAPI would only treat it as `String`.

Comment: The `file` parameter showing up as having the "string" type is correct (in OAS 3.0, files are defined as binary strings). What's incorrect is that it shows up as a query parameter instead of a request body field. Should the annotation maybe be [`@RequestPart`](https://springdoc.org/#is-file-upload-supported) instead of `@RequestParam`?

Comment: Tried with @RequestPart as well. Same behavior and the "Execute" button doesn't work.

Comment: Hi. Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Along the line of Rafael's post, this worked for me:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> xslTransform(
           @Parameter(description = "Upload a xsl and a xml file", content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE))
           @RequestPart(value = "Upload 2 files", required = true)
           MultipartFile[] files) {
........
   }
```

I use openapi version 1.6.15. the only issue is that I cannot set the maximum number of items in the array. Users might add more items than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String createComment(
        @RequestPart(value = "message", required = false) @Size(max = 2000) String message,
        @RequestPart(value = "files", required = false) MultipartFile[] files
) {
    return "test";
}
```

with springdoc 1.7.0 works correctly

Answer (score -1):

You could use `@RequestPart` with `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`.

Can be combined with `@Parameter` from OpenAPI (`io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations`):

```
@PostMapping("/files", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFiles(
    @Parameter(content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file,
    @RequestPart(value = "comment", required = false ) String comment
) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    log.debug("Total files to store: {}", file.length);
    log.debug("comment: {}", comment);
    fileService.storeFile(Arrays.asList(file), comment);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(environment.getProperty("file.upload.success"));
}
```

On `swagger-ui` should show `multipart/form-data` selected on right:

[image]

---

##### Reference:

- [POST method with MultipartFile as RequestPart is considered as String in swagger3 open-api Springboot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74149274/post-method-with-multipartfile-as-requestpart-is-considered-as-string-in-swagger)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this and let you know.